# How to fix 'rimraf is not a recognized command' in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, .net-core

After creating the .NET Core / React & Redux project template and attempting to start the application, the react compile crashes with `rimraf not recognized.`

This is on Windows 10, node.js version 10.15.3. I have tried uninstalling/installing node.js multiple times and running multiple different npm commands. It seems like powershell is incorrectly linking to rimraf for some reason.

`npm echo %PATH%` provides the correct path to the ./node_modules/.bin directory. And running that path followed by e.g. `/rimraf` works properly. The command in `package.json` is `"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start"`.

Answer (score 47):

I had to manually run **npm install** to make it work.

open command line (e.g. from Visual Studio: Tools -> Command Line -> Developer Command Prompt)

go to ClientApp (`cd ClientApp`) folder of your project and type:

```
npm install
```

Comment: I had this issue and this was the solution for me, but it was because I didn't have any node_modules installed in the ClientApp folder of the project.

Comment: If you have this error  `unable to resolve dependency tree`
  run this command: **npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps**

Comment: npm install creates this issue, so this response is a bit invalid.

Answer (score 39):

I finally got rid of this error by installing rimraf globally

`npm install rimraf -g`

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

install:

```
npm install rimraf --save-dev
```

set your custom command in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf build && tsc",
  "start": "node build/index.js"
}
```

Use it

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 4):

Delete node modules folder in your web project. Do npm install.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, if you get this error,

"rimraf' is not recognized"

First of all, the below assumes you have node installed.  To check if nodejs is installed, open a cmd/powershell window and type: node -v

It should return the version number.

Also, before you do a build in VS2019, make sure you have updated all the nuget packages.

After verifying the above, do the following:

1. go to the myappproject/clientapp folder and delete the /nodemodules folder.
2. from the clientapp folder, open up a powershell or cmd prompt
3. run npm install

Rebuild.  This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but rimraf was already installed globally. Had to manually delete node modules and then install them back again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue a couple of times as well.
The problem on my machine is that some applications seem to override everything in system's path variable and npm install doesn't always fix this, even after a clean global install.
You can manually add the npm path to the variable, this always fixes the problem for me (at least until I've installed/updated applications that override the path variable again).

> C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm

1. Search for "edit environment variables" in the windows start menu.
2. Select the PATH variable from the list
3. Press the "Edit..." button
4. If the above path is not in the list, add it using the "New" button
5. Press OK on both windows and restart your Command Prompt